# read html content of a page using ajax

Tags: c#, html, ajax

i have this need.. I hope someone can give me a right advice !

i have to read the whole html content of a page using an ajax call, it is necessary that the client who is visiting my page is who that make this request to read the html content, and not my application (i mean using downloadstring method of c#)

After this, i need to read the response of the ajax call (in this case the html content of the page setted in the "url:" parameter of the ajax call) server-side (in my code-behind)

how i can do that? is possible?

Thank you for your help..

Stefano

Comment: the html that i have to read is in another domain! :)

Answer (score 1):

Stefano, 
You could get the html content through ajax using, for exemplo, jquery get like this:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  //data is the html
});
```

After that you can make another ajax call sending the data to your "code-behind", as you can see in the complete code:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        data: "htmlData=" data
        type: "POST",
        url: '/code_behind.aspx',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
 });
```

I hope that this helps.

Comment: I think that it doesn't work... i try but i can't read answer of ajax call..
i read this in other topic: 

"You're running into restrictions imposed by the Same Origin Policy. In short, AJAX calls to a different domain are prohibited and will always fail.

You need to either use JSONP (mostly applicable to data returned by APIs) or proxy the request through your own server/domain.
"

Comment: Well, you did not mention on your question that the html lived in a separate domain. You should edit it because this is very important information.